# EC2s in an Autoscaling group across 2 subnets in same VPC can't connect to each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I need 2 EC2s in an Autoscaling group across 2 AZs in the same private VPC to connect to each other but they can't even ping each other using their private IP addresses.

There is no NACL and I have opened all ports to the same Security Group that these 2 EC2s use. They also share the same routing table (172.31.0.0/16 local - in Route Table).

I am using us-east-1. Any advice please?

Comment: Ping uses ICMP so unless you opened ICMP in addition to TCP in the security group, it won't work. Otherwise, please provide details of exactly what protocol/ports you are trying to communicate over, what software you have running on those port(s) on the servers, and what operating system the servers are running.

Comment: Can you have no NACL?  The default NACL is sufficient, but there's an allow line in there that is important.

Comment: @MarkB I opened ICMP as well and it didn't work. I was trying on install MariaDB Galera on Amazon Linux 2. Here's the guide I am using: https://galeracluster.com/library/training/tutorials/galera-on-aws.html

Comment: @erik258 Apologies. I meant I didn't set up any NACL.

Comment: Your first step for troubleshooting would be to remove `firewalld`.  That's an unnecessary layer of complexity.  It's also unclear why you are talking about an auto-scaling group.  You can't run a Galera cluster in an auto-scaling group.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Sorry but I am new at this. Why can't I run a Galera cluster in an autoscaling group?

Comment: @TobyT the short answer is that Galera just doesn't work in a way that is compatible with auto-scaling groups.  Notice the tutorial doesn't mention auto-scaling despite being specifically about AWS.  Clusters are not dynamic and nodes are not trivially disposable, as an auto-scaling group would imply.  The loss of half or more of the nodes in a Galera cluster takes the cluster offline and requires manual intervention.  Joining a cluster requires Galera to know the (static) IP of at least one current member.  Clusters with even numbers of nodes are more fragile than with odd.  The list goes on.

Comment: ...and none of this speaks negatively of Galera.  Database scaling and resilience is a non-trivial problem.